# How to run perl script with a few arguments from php

Tags: php, python, perl, shell

My html webpage calls a php script to upload files to the server from a local computer as follows.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">
<p><b><h3>  <font color="#003366"> (1) Upload your reading text file.  </font> 
</h3> </b> </p>
<INPUT type="file" name="uploaded" size="50" >
<br/>
<input type="submit" name="files" value="upload">
</form>
```

In order to process with an uploaded file, my php script calls a shell script

```
$output=system('/bin/sh connector_0.sh');
```

and my shell script is composed of a series of python/perl scripts.

```
#!/bin/sh

python main_senselearner_final_0.py 

senseLearner.pl -i Uploaded_Files/slinput_0.txt -o Uploaded_Files/presloutput_0
.txt -model modelNNCollocations -model modelJJCollocations -model modelVBColloc
ations -pos

python smutngslout_0.py 

python genhtml_0.py
```

Now, the problem is the following: all the python scripts in shell script worked fine through php. But the perl script didn't work.

When I run the shell script by myself in my server, all four scripts in the shell worked perfectly.  However, when I run the shell script from php, only the perl script doesn't work.

Would you please give me any tips to solve this problem?

Many thanks!!!

Comment: I corrected your formatting - use the code formatting toolbar button, or indent code by four spaces.

Comment: Capture the output and standard error of the shell script. Check `$?` after each line in the shell script.

Comment: **"Doesn't work" doesn't help.** What *specifically* happens (error messages, log entries, mangled output, spilled milk, kitty fur on the couch)? @mobrule: `set -x` might be useful, too.

Comment: Paul, mobrule, Dennis, Thank you for your nice help and tips! :)
@ Dennis, nothing happened. The script just didn't output any.

Answer (score 1):

This is very likely a permissions problem. Try setting the files that the perl script reads to a+rw and see if it works then. If so, then you need to find out the user running php (likely the apache user) and make sure that they can read/write the relevant files.
Also make sure the Perl script is executable by the php user (apache).

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that the user that Apache/PHP is running as (usually apache) does not have permissions for `Uploaded_Files/slinput_0.txt` or `Uploaded_Files/presloutput_0.txt`.

Just guessing but apache would need read for the `slinput_0.txt` file, read/write for `presloutput_0.txt` and read/write/exec for the directory `Uploaded_Files`

The reason it works when you try it is you are running as your user and most likely have permissions to write to the webroot.

Comment: Just guessing but apache would need read for the slinput_0.txt  file, read/write for presloutput_0.txt and read/write/exec for the directory Uploaded_Files

==> Yes, that is what I guessed too. So I tried to set those files read/write using chmod 755/(or even 777), it returns "chmod: changing permissions of `slinput_0.txt': Operation not permitted" Would you give me some tips how to solve it? 

Thank you very much!

Comment: that means you don't have permissions on those files - if you have root access to the webserver you need to `sudo chmod`. Those directories might already be owned by apache but not have the correct permissions to read/write/exec. If you do not have root access to the webserver you would need to get help from your hosting company to fix some permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try
senseLearner.pl -i Up ... -pos > /var/log/senseLearner.log 2>&1
(and look to that log file after)

and maybe you can try to specify interpreter like
/path/to/perl senseLearner.pl -i Up ... -pos > /var/log/senseLearner.log 2>&1